# Typescript Key Issue "Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'."

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I had looked over some other issues that were similiar to this one, however some of them had talked about modifying the tsconfig.json and changing the compiler options to include

```
"strictNullChecks": true,
"noImplicitAny": false,
```

However, my code looks like this:

```
export interface DetailedRankings {
show_id: number;
name: string;
category: string;
episodes: number;
story?: number;
characters?: number;
overall?: number;
}

function handleInputChange(category: keyof DetailedRankings, event: string, index: number) {
    const value_number: number = parseFloat(event);
    let list: DetailedRankings[] = [...detailed_ranks];
    let obj: DetailedRankings = list[index];
    obj[category] = value_number <--- Having issue with this.
}
```

I am under the impression that the reason this issue is being caused is because I have string and number within the interface. I am just a bit lost on what is causing the issue of.

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are not restricting your function to only take keys where the type is `number`. This may lead to runtime errors. What is preventing me from calling the function like this?

```
handleInputChange("category", "0", 0)
```

Now `obj["category"]` will have a number assigned to it which breaks your interface defintion. The error is warning you from this unsoundness.

You could compute all `number` properties in a seperate type and use it as the argument type in your function.

```
type DetailedRankingsNumberProps = keyof {
  [K in keyof DetailedRankings as number extends DetailedRankings[K]
    ? K 
    : never
  ]: K
}

function handleInputChange(
  category: DetailedRankingsNumberProps, 
  event: string, 
  index: number
) {
  const value_number: number = parseFloat(event);
  let list: DetailedRankings[] = [];
  let obj: DetailedRankings = list[index] 

  obj[category] = value_number // No error anymore
}

handleInputChange("category", "0", 0) // compile time error now
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEWBkwQBtgATAJUyQGtkBzAZzgG8AoOOZgCwgDuAfQQUAXHCQBXALYAjNAG4ukzDOATmMKE2XdsmVI2gBPTdt0rgYBMwgVgzCdPlKVW0wH5nshVD1w2LyYUDioUMzekr5u3BAAbmiYpKRRLn7KAL4cHDAmYHiExGSUNPRMzAByMVAAClAQYKwAvHB0wCYQ6OwqANoA0ohIbR1dBEQk5NS0DEgscJis6WhwoKhIFKxFk6UzFQMAuircnnCDx3DOwIlQKgcS-RzZHOhSSNgwCBDDwRvkAJJIMBSGAAYV+jGAAAoDEZTBJtiVpuU5lUavVGswADSrRIocw6OY45AOEA+VxQACUPX03y0cHiySkwCEyyg5L8cFaYBCzGAADFSBBDFDrsAUJSAuR4KRbDAERMkWVZixegcuXA1VKiHAIHIAFYK4pTZUVDWyrS9EmgdU5OIG3qw4DGKAmdWtRmkZmsmpPHIcX4UAFAkHg2iQqEAIg8rsjOMjAAY43AE5SgA)

Comment: I am curious about the wording of the original error message, though, as `let x = obj[category]` gives me `let x: string | number | undefined`, not 'never'.

Comment: `obj[category]` is indeed a union of different types. But if you want to assign something to it, the value must confirm to an **intersection** of all the types for type safety. And an intersection of `string & number & undefined` is `never`.

Comment: I see. Also, I found that in your current answer, `handleInputChange("story", "0", 0)` causes a compile error, even though `obj['story'] = 0` makes sense.

Comment: @qrsngky - yes, my mistake. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that typescript cannot guarentee that the value of `obj[category]` is assignable `number` so it says that `obj[category]` is assignable `never` as it's not assignable.

A little hack you could do is just convert `obj` to be a type `Record<string, number>` or `Record<keyof DetailedRankings, number>`

Like this for example:

```
function handleInputChange(category: keyof DetailedRankings, event: string, index: number) {
    const value_number: number = parseFloat(event);
    let list: DetailedRankings[] = [...detailed_ranks];
    let obj: Record<keyof DetailedRankings, number> = list[index];
    obj[category] = value_number
}
```

Obviously this has the drawback of not being a DetailedRankings type anymore...

I believe it's just a drawback of strict typescript. As a programmer you know only `number` keys of `category` are passed to your function but there's no way to tell typescript that in strict mode (as far as I know)

Comment: Other option would be to extract all number properties to a separate interface that `DetailedRankings` would then extend. you can then use `keyof newInterface` and since all the properties are numbers it would infer correctly

Comment: I get `Type 'DetailedRankings' is not assignable to type 'Record<keyof DetailedRankings, number>'.` when I try `let obj: Record<keyof DetailedRankings, number> = list[index];`